# Call function, which randomize parameters for test, within decorators

Tags: python, loops, testing, decorator

I am in proccess of writing variety of tests. 
and most of them look like this:

```
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("name, price, count, type, countPoints, device", [
        ('test_name1', 3001, 1, 'key', 1, CAR),
        ('test_name2', 3000, 167, '', 1, MOTO),
        # and so on, choosing different parameters
    ])
    def test_getItemTradePreferences(name, price, count, type, countPoints, appid):
            assert testing_funtion(price,count,type,countPoints,appid) == val_obj.getItemTradePreferences(name,price,count,type,countPoints)
```

then I thought it will be better not to type parameters manually but write a function which will use random and do it for me.

```
def generate_testing_values():
    return ['test_nameX', randint(0, 3000), randint(1, 1000), '', randint(1, 1000), choice([CAR, MOTO])]
```

and call test like this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("name, price, count, type, countPoints, device", [
        generate_testing_values(),
        generate_testing_values(),
        generate_testing_values(),
        # can I call generate_testing_values() in loop?
    ])
    def test_getItemTradePreferences(name, price, count, type, countPoints, appid):
            assert testing_funtion(price,count,type,countPoints,appid) == val_obj.getItemTradePreferences(name,
price,
count,type,
countPoints)
```

But can I somehow call this generate_testing_values() in loop within decorator?
I have not found the solution yet, if you know please share.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should build generate_testing_values() function to return all the values together.